# Keycloak: API to check if user token has roles for a particular resource

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I have a keycloak server setup. I am using the token endpoint: `http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token` to authenticate a user and generate a token. This token I understand can be used in subsequent calls to verify if it is a valid user.

However, I am not sure how do I use this to authorize the user? ie verify if this user has the roles to access a resource.

I see that it is possible to configure a resource URI under the client section. But once that is done, I want to be able to read the token and verify if this user has the roles to access this resource.

Right now, this is what I am doing:
I have used spring boot here.

```
doSomething(String token)
{
 1. get token info using: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
 2. from this get the roles the user has
 3. Manually check the roles required for the above function. (Right now, this is set in a simple switch statement)
 4. If the role obtained from step 2 matches what we get in step 3, go ahead. Else return failure.
}
```

I want to know if step 3 above can be done in a better way. I know taht you can set a resource in clients from the keycloak console. What I was hoping is we could replace the 4 steps above with something like:

```
keycloakAPIToAuthorizeToken(token,resource)
```

which would tell me whether this user has the roles (obtained from token) to access this resource.

Please suggest if this is doable.

Thanks in advance.
Om

Comment: Authorization might get complex. I think here best practice is keycloak's resource servers. Declare your resources and map the permission which is obtained by policies. Then you can ask to resource server either the token owner has that permission or not. However, what if your auth is simplest one, i am not sure you have to deal with resource servers. At that time, you might use the mappers to map roles into the token as a claim or map to userinfo end-point and ask with token.

Answer (score 0):

There are MANY ways to do this. One of them is to use Keycloak's roles, and assign those roles to users. That way, in your server/api you can check if the user has that role and proceed or reject the call.

Example, in my api project, I have some endpoints that are exclusive for system administrators, so I have a role SystemAdministrators:

[image]

and then, if you go to Users, Role Mappings, you can add that role to the users to set as admins:

[image]

Then, any api call should include a bearer token (obtained from the Keycloak login), in your code, you can decode this jwt (it will depend what language you are using, I use python so its pretty simple), it will have an element "realm_access" and inside it, a "role" element, example:

```
  "realm_access": {
      "roles": [
          "offline_access",
          "uma_authorization",
          "SystemAdministrators"
]
```

},

If that element contains the role SystemAdministrators, you know is a system administrator.

I found this is the simplest way to do it. You can get fancy and use role attributes to determine individual options inside screens, etc (attributes are key/value pairs so the way I implemented this is, the key is an option name and the value is the permission level, for example: "screen1": "read", "screen2": "write", and so on. For this, you would need to use the keycloak admin api: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/6.0/rest-api/index.html#_roles_resource which has many endpoints that can help you.

Comment: I believe this is what the author of the question wants to get away from by moving the configuration of the access to resources to Keycloak.